# Problems installing EpiServer 6

Tags: episerver, episerver-6

When installing Epi Server 6.0.530.0 I choose "Custom" but a while later I get an error ("Could not find stored procedure 'sp_dboption'"). This is my first installation and I've never worked with Epi (allthough I've been coding .NET since 10+ years) so, naturally, I feel a bit insecure. (And by that I mean that I have no idea what can be the problem nor how to kill it.)

I have SQL Server 2008 and VC# 2010 (both Express) on my Win 7 Pro.

Suggestions?

*I also have the longer, full error message in the installation log but I'm not posting it here because I don't want to be lynched. It's really long... So I've uploaded it [here](http://www.viltersten.com/files/text_01.txt). Joyful reading!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbo.sp_dboption was removed in SQL2012, are you positive the installer is using SQL2008 and not an instance of SQL2012?

Comment: I had some problems installing (or running, I can't remember) Server 2012 so I removed it and went back to Server 2008 (I had a deadline so it was a crazy rush hour that time). There might be some issues with that - I just didn't notice it until now. Perhaps I should remove the whole shabang and reinstall it all... On the - why would EpiServer installer get stuck on such an obvious issue? It doesn't sound like a MS product...

Comment: Now I've uninstalled everything called SQL and then installed the newest release of Server 2012 express. As you predict, I'm getting the error message because that SP's been dropped. So, what do I do about it?

Comment: You could always create the stored procedure. This method worked for me. http://dotnetcake.blogspot.ie/2012/06/installing-episerver-6-r2-on-windows-8.html

Answer (score 0):

Does the account performing the install have the correct priveliges in the database? I have often run into problems with that, since the install dialogs always confuse me.

Comment: It might be something like that. I noticed that my installation of SQL Server is out of order. Some items are listed three times, others are missing. I've been trying to uninstall everything and reinstall Server 12 but it takes such a time...